# Base 10 to Base 2 Conversion with large integers in python

Tags: python, binary, numbers, converters

I'm working on a number converter in python and am finding it difficult to correctly convert large decimal values (larger than 2^53) from decimal to binary.  I have done many random tests to find the breaking point but I'm not sure why it is breaking. I thought Python 3 allowed for arbitrarily large numbers.  I might be losing some data converting between str and int values. Thank you for your help. Here is the code I am using:

```
# @param: num is an integer >= 0 
# @return: A string containing the converted binary value of num 
def base10to2(num):
    if(not bool(re.match(decimals, str(num)))):
        return "num must be a decimal number string [0-9]."
    if(int(num) <= 1):
        return num
    binaryValue = ''
    decimalRemainder = int(num)
    while decimalRemainder > 0:
        binaryValue = str(decimalRemainder % 2) + binaryValue
        decimalRemainder = math.floor(decimalRemainder / 2)    
    return binaryValue
```

Here are some of my random test results:

> error bin <--> dec at decimal value 57578088768095921 and binary value
> 11001100100011101111011101110111110111100100011010110000.
> 11001100 10001110 11110111 01110111 11011110 01000110 10110001 should be
> 11001100 10001110 11110111 01110111 11011110 01000110 10110000
>
> error bin <--> dec at decimal value 94158773465990610 and binary value
> 101001110100001001110011111010100111011010100010111010000.
> 101001110100001001110011111010100111011010100010111010010 should be
> 101001110100001001110011111010100111011010100010111010000
>
> error bin <--> dec at decimal value 27741136442133437 and binary value
> 1100010100011100110101010100111010011001000101110111100.
> 1100010100011100110101010100111010011001000101110111100 should be
> 1100010100011100110101010100111010011001000101110111101
>
> error bin <--> dec at decimal value 102400897160966081 and binary
> value 101101011110011010001001011001011111101011110111111000000.
> 101101011110011010001001011001011111101011110111111000000 should be
> 101101011110011010001001011001011111101011110111111000001
>
> error bin <--> dec at decimal value 61449679276206615 and binary value
> 11011010010100000010100001100000110100011110101000011000.
> 11011010010100000010100001100000110100011110101000011000 should be
> 11011010010100000010100001100000110100011110101000010111
>
> error bin <--> dec at decimal value 32630026885393859 and binary value
> 1110011111011001101011000101001100000111110110111000100.
> 111 0011 1110 1100 1101 0110 0010 1001 1000 0011 1110 1101 1100 0100 should be
> 0011 1110 1100 1101 0110 0010 1001 1000 0011 1110 1101 1100 0011
>
> error bin <--> dec at decimal value 28823706477206651 and binary value
> 1100110011001110000001000100001101011110001110001111100.
> 1100110 01100111 00000010 00100001 10101111 00011100 01111100 should be
> 1100110 01100111 00000010 00100001 10101111 00011100 01111011
>
> error bin <--> dec at decimal value 32300284354028835 and binary value
> 1110010110000001110111111111111000100001110010100100100.
> 1110010 11000000 11101111 11111111 00010000 11100101 00100100 should be
> 1110010 11000000 11101111 11111111 00010000 11100101 00100011
>
> error bin <--> dec at decimal value 15026178163056103 and binary value
> 110101011000100011101010111011101111011001110111101001.
> 110101 01100010 00111010 10111011 10111101 10011101 11101001 should be
> 110101 01100010 00111010 10111011 10111101 10011101 11100111

It seems only the last 4 bits are incorrect in these cases.

Here is the procedure to convert from base 2 to base 10 I have (just in case this is relevant).

```
# @param: num is binary whole number
# @return: A string containing the converted decimal value of num
def base2to10(num):
    if(not bool(re.match(binary, str(num)))):
        return "num must be a binary number string [0-1]."
    digits = []
    placeValue = 1
    decimalValue = 0
    digits = list(num)
    for i in range(len(digits)):
        decimalValue += placeValue * int(digits[len(digits) - i - 1])
        placeValue *= 2
    return decimalValue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
decimalRemainder = math.floor(decimalRemainder / 2)
```

introduces inaccuracy into your calculation, because you are performing float division, which is only approximate, because floats have limited precision.

Instead you can use

```
decimalRemainder = decimalRemainder // 2
```

which performs the division with ints and is precise.

With that change, `base10to2(94158773465990610)` gives `'101001110100001001110011111010100111011010100010111010010'`, which is correct.

See also the [built-in bin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin).

Answer (score 1):

### Just use the built-in function `bin`

```bash
Python 3.10. ...
>>>
>>> bin(94158773465990610)[2:] == '101001110100001001110011111010100111011010100010111010010'
True
```

```py
def base10to2(a: int) -> int:
    """ Convert a_{10} to abs(a_{2}). """
    return int(bin(abs(a))[2:])
```